# SqlGeography get polygons from multipolygon

Tags: c#, polygon, geography, sqlgeography

I have table `Town` with column `TownBoundary` that contains polygon of relevant town (`geography` datatype).

For each town I get polygon data that I need to generate KML(XML) files like:

```
sqlg = SqlGeography.STPolyFromText(new SqlChars(
town.TownBoundary.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText),
town.TownBoundary.CoordinateSystemId);
for (int i = 1; i <= sqlg.STNumPoints(); i++)
{
    SqlGeography point = sqlg.STPointN(i);
    var pLong = (point.Long).ToString().Replace(",", ".");
    var pLat = (point.Lat).ToString().Replace(",", ".");
    double dLong = double.Parse(pLong, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    double dLat = double.Parse(pLat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    kmlCoordinates.Add(new Vector(dLat, dLong)); //one point od polygon
}
```

Values of `town.TownBoundary.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText` begins with `POLYGON(..`

But recently I have realised that some towns contains more polygons and `WellKnownText` begins with `MULTIPOLYGON(..` and function `STPolyFromText` ends up in error.

I have placed this in `try{}` block, but in `catch{}` - if value is multipolygon - is it possible to somehow get individual polygons? I know there is method `STMPolyFromText`, but I can't acccess individual polygons there, only points as in method `STPolyFromText`.

My goal is to split multipolygon to polygons and than foreach polygon do the same method as above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it, in method `STMPolyFromText` I can get array of polygons using `STNumGeometries`.

```
sqlg = SqlGeography.STMPolyFromText(
new SqlChars(town.TownBoundary.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText),
town.TownBoundary.CoordinateSystemId);
for (int i = 1; i <= sqlg.STNumGeometries(); i++)
{
 SqlGeography poly = sqlg.STGeometryN(i);
 //foreach poly
}
```